# A Regex to ignore a set of words

Tags: regex, cpu-word

Is there a way to set regex to ignore a set of words separated by space?

I have different products names like:
"Matrix 10X, 10 ml + DISPENSER"
"Matrix 10X,10ml + DISPENSER" where the quantity varies

What I'm trying to do is to replace using regex all words except for:
"10 ml" | "10 ML" | "10ml" ---> these are to be ignored

I have found a code to replace all characters except words separated by space (like "10 ml")
https://regex101.com/r/bG8vB4/5

and to replace them when they are together (like "10ml")

https://regex101.com/r/bG8vB4/4

but can find a way to mix them together to keep just "10 ml" OR "10 ML" OR "10ml" and remove other characters up to the end of the string

Comment: You may match these words `(?i)\b10\s*ML` and skip, `(?i)\b10\s*ML(*SKIP)(*F)` then match other "words", `(?i)\b10\s*ML(*SKIP)(*F)|\S+`

Answer (score 0):

Regexps are a mathematical model to do efficient computer recognition of strings.  As easy as getting a regular expression to match a string if it has *any* of some words, math demonstrates that the regexp to get a matcher of strings that just matches a string if it has none of those words is possible.  The way to get such a regexp, although is far more complex.

On regular expressions theory, a regular language is one that allows you to set a finite automaton from a regular expression, and the automaton that recognizes a string if the original doesn't is feasible by just switching all accept states into non-accepting states.  Once done this, the hardest part is to build a regular expression that matches that automaton (that is possible, but the final regular expression is far more complex, in general than the original)  This can be solved with an example (a simple one) and you'll see that that is a complex thing (of course, some regexp libraries allow you to use an operand for this, but you don't specify if the one you are using does)  One such sample is when you have to recognize a simple C language comment.  A comment is a string delimited by the sequences `/*` and `*/` but in the inner part, you cannot have the sequence `*/`.

The first approach could be to use the following regexp:

```
\/\*.*\*\/
```

but that fails, as the inner regexp includes the recognition of `*/` as part of it, so `/* bla bla bla */ bla bla bla */`  will be recognized as a comment in whole (it should end at the first `*/`) so wee need a regexp that recognizes anything but not something that includes `*/`

Such subexpression is:

```
([^*]|\*[^/])*
```

which means and undefinite concatenation of characters different that `*`, or sequences that, including the first character as `*` are not followed by `/`.  If you follow that concatenation, you'll see that it's impossible to form a sequence `*/` leading to our final regexp:

```
\/\*([^*]|\*[^/])*\*\/
```

(now you see how the things complicate)

To extend this to a single word (as `word`, more than two letters) you have to consider that you can allow:

```
([^w]|w[^o]|wo[^r]|wor[^d])*
```

in the set, and if you have two words (like `foo` and `bar`) you have to write:

```
([^f]|f[^o]|fo[^o]|[^b]|b[^a]|ba[^r])*
```

meaning that for each word you have such regexps, making the final regexp a bit complicated.  Also, there can be interactions between words if some can be the prefix to another or some have the same prefix chars.  This also can have the problem that the compilation of regexps into finite automata has produced many libraries that consider the `|` operator non conmutative and resolve them in a non conmutative way, leading to erroneous results.

You have not explained also what you mean with ignoring.  If you mean matching them and pass around, is different to mean to ignore the whole line they could appear on.  The regexps then (an the definition of the problem you need to solve is quite different ---my explanation was in the sense of rejecting a full sentence if it has *any* of the words on it, which probably is not what you mean)  So please, explain (in your question) what do you mean with:

- accepting you have matched a sentence containing a word.
- rejecting such a sentence.
- what are you rejecting (or ignoring) at all.

Rejecting just a word, is simply selecting a sencence that contains that word, and mark the word to be able to pass over it.  But that's a different problem, and it requires to select sentences that *do have the word*.